# How is the following matrix in reduce echelon form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the matrix

$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
    1 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
According to my textbook, this matrix is in reduced echelon form.
However the rules of reduce echelon form state that all other elements in a column that contains a leading 1 are zero.

Would the 4 at position (1,2) not break that rule and make this matrix not be in reduced echelon form?

Thank you.

Comment: ??? That $4$ is not a "leading $1$". Look up the definition of "leading $1$"...

Comment: Yup, just mixed it up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, what's the problem then? In every column that contains a leading $1$ all other elements are zeros. The $4$ is in the second column which has no leading $1$. Don't get confused between rows and columns.

Comment: Thank you, I mixed up the row and column, I see how it works now!

Answer (score 1):

Let us define "**pivotal column**" as the column containing the pivot.

Now the column having element 4 is NOT a pivotal column.

According to echelon form, only pivotal column has all elements (in the column) zero, except the pivot itself.

Since second column is not pivotal, it is perfectly a row-reduced echelon form.

Comment: Thank you! I see how it's reduced now, that makes a lot of sense!